# How to set multiple columns into rows in sql query

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I want to convert the columns into rows using SQL Server. I have already tried unpivot but not enough knowledge to make it only can make the one column

```
SELECT Unit,Excess_Reactivity ,Refuelling_required,MBP,MCP ,CPPF,Date FROM yourTable // select statement

//insert  to check data
INSERT INTO yourTable
    (Unit,Excess_Reactivity ,Refuelling_required,MBP ,MCP ,CPPF ,Date)
VALUES
    ('TAP-4','52','test1','12','96','35','2019-06-11 00:00:00.000')

INSERT INTO yourTable
    (Unit,Excess_Reactivity ,Refuelling_required,MBP ,MCP ,CPPF ,Date)
VALUES
    ('TAP-2','52','test1','12','96','35','2019-06-11 00:00:00.000')

INSERT INTO yourTable
    (Unit,Excess_Reactivity ,Refuelling_required,MBP ,MCP ,CPPF ,Date)
VALUES
    ('TAP-3','52','test1','12','96','35','2019-06-11 00:00:00.000')
```

This is  table

```
+--------+--------+---------+-----+-----+------+------------+
|  UNit  | excess | refuell | MBp | MCP | CPPF |    DATE    |
+--------+--------+---------+-----+-----+------+------------+
| TAPS-4 |     52 | test1   |  12 |  96 |   35 | 11/06/2019 |
| TAPS-3 |     52 | test1   |  13 |  96 |   35 | 11/06/2019 |
| TAPS-2 |     52 | test1   |  42 |  96 |   35 | 11/06/2019 |
| TAPS-1 |     52 | test1   |  18 |  96 |   35 | 11/06/2019 |
+--------+--------+---------+-----+-----+------+------------+
```

I want like this as shown below:

```
Values   TAPS-4  TAPS-3  TAPS-2 TAPS-1
--------------------------------------
excess    52      52     52      52
MBp       12      13     42      18
MCP       96      96     96      96
CPPF      35      35     35      35
```

Comment: Do you need dynamic pivot or you know your `VALUES` ?

Comment: why you undo my format?

Comment: yes nees dynamic which collects the names and set into columns and the multiple columns data would be set into rows

Comment: Juan Carlos Oropeza  sry adding first times in stackoverflow need these to solve very quickly i was not knowing abt the format you change you can change it again sry

Comment: I revert to my version you can add the changes now

Comment: no changes just waiting for the solution please help !

Answer (score 1):

- first you need to unpivot your table, take note you need convert your data to the same type because every data will go to the same column.
- then you can pivot to your desire result.
- if need it convert back to original data type.

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2febc/8)**

```
WITH unpvt as (
  SELECT Unit, Attribute, Vals
  FROM ( SELECT Unit, 
                cast(excess as nvarchar(100)) as excess, 
                cast(MBp as nvarchar(100)) as MBp, 
                cast(MCP as nvarchar(100)) as MCP,  
                cast(CPPF as nvarchar(100)) as CPPF
         FROM Table1) as p
  UNPIVOT
       (Vals FOR Attribute in (excess, MBp, MCP, CPPF)
       ) as unpvt
)
SELECT Attribute, [TAPS-4],  [TAPS-3], [TAPS-2], [TAPS-1]
FROM ( SELECT Unit, Attribute, Vals
       FROM unpvt) p 
PIVOT (
         MAX(Vals) FOR  Unit IN 
         ([TAPS-4], [TAPS-3], [TAPS-2], [TAPS-1])
      ) pvt
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Attribute | TAPS-4 | TAPS-3 | TAPS-2 | TAPS-1 |
|-----------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|      CPPF |     35 |     35 |     35 |     35 |
|    excess |     52 |     52 |     52 |     52 |
|       MBp |     12 |     13 |     42 |     18 |
|       MCP |     96 |     96 |     96 |     96 |
```

**Note:** Try `SELECT * FROM unpvt` in the sql fiddle to see the intermediate result.

Comment: Yupz thanks very much the way i want and also, can i bring the taps-4 , taps-3 , taps-2 value dynamically by calling function in it ?